# How to replace a washer-fluid pump on 2008 Equinox

Tags: chevrolet, windshield-washer

Looking for directions on replacing the washer-fluid pump on a 2008 Chevy Equinox. I've found that the fuse works both the pump and the wipers, and the wipers still work. Seeing as I do not hear the pump run I'm guessing it's a failure in the pump.

The pump it's self is at the bottom on the tank. The tank is right in front of the drivers wheel well. But from what I can see I'm not able to access the pump from the wheel well or under the vehicle. I'm also not able to just pull the whole tank as it's got feet that hook under the battery mount.

Any tips or pointers are welcome. Hopefully I've given enough detail.

Comment: Did you check the wiring?

Comment: I cant even get down that far to check the wiring.

Answer (score 1):

Everything I've been able to find says the tank has to come out to get at the pump.  I'm not sure how to solve the issue with the battery mount.  It's probably worth checking to see if you can get at it from the wheel well with the wheel off (might have to to remove the fender liner).

Assuming you can get at the pump, you can verify that it's getting power with a multimeter or a test light.  If it's not getting power, the suspects will be the switch/button in the passenger compartment, the relay and a control module, not necessarily in that order.

Answer (score 1):

To access the Wiper reservoir tank you need to remove the cover over the battery.Then disconnect the battery and remove it. The Coolant tank bolt is combined with the wash tank and needs to be removed. To make it easier to remove and replace the washer tank take out the other coolant tank bolt. Remove the two smaller bolts holding the wash tank in place.Now remove the battery plastic case 4 bolts and remove it.Now you have access to the Washer tank to do what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Mine doesnt have feet under the battery, although i thiught the same thing. You are probably being to gentle with it as i was before i got mad. There is just a stem that goes into a slot, so youll have to pull up on it before maneuvering it out. Helps to tie back the radiator overflow.